# BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class ... because it does not exist

Tags: spring, maven, jira, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

atlas-package runs without errors. But I got errors with Quick Reload.
Error is:
JiraRendererPlugin.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

- I imported this interface in java code. No errors while compilation still.
- I changed dependency for jira-core in pom.xml. From "provided" to "runtime" => I got out of memory error while compilation. Added memory to maven - doesn't help.

**Errors**

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2020-06-02 20:17:15,258 QuickReload - Plugin Installer INFO      [c.a.plugin.loaders.ScanningPluginLoader] Removed plugin 'com.vladmak.ringcentral.jira-cmp-plgin'
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2020-06-02 20:17:15,314 QuickReload - Plugin Installer INFO      [c.a.plugin.util.WaitUntil] Plugins that have yet to be enabled: (1): [com.vladmak.ringcentral.jira-cmp-plgin], 300 seconds remaining
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2020-06-02 20:17:15,337 ThreadPoolAsyncTaskExecutor::Thread 52 ERROR      [c.a.p.osgi.factory.OsgiPlugin] Unable to start the plugin container for plugin 'com.vladmak.ringcentral.jira-cmp-plgin'
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.vladmak.ringcentral.jiracmp.CMRRenderer]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/atlassian/jira/issue/fields/renderer/JiraRendererPlugin.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:182)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:261)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:444)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:414)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:362)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$3.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:254)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.startRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:220)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.stageOne(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:224)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.refresh(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:177)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:157)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.activator.LifecycleManager$1.run(LifecycleManager.java:207)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/atlassian/jira/issue/fields/renderer/JiraRendererPlugin.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
```

**Class**

```
package com.vladmak.ringcentral.jiracmp;

import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.renderer.wiki.AtlassianWikiRenderer;

import com.atlassian.event.api.EventPublisher;
//import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.renderer.IssueRenderContext;
//import com.atlassian.jira.plugin.renderer.JiraRendererModuleDescriptor;
import com.atlassian.jira.util.velocity.VelocityRequestContextFactory;
import com.atlassian.jira.config.properties.ApplicationProperties;
import com.atlassian.jira.config.FeatureManager;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.imports.JiraImport;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.renderer.JiraRendererPlugin;
//import com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.export.ExportAsService;
//import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.renderer.*;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


@Component
public  class CMRRenderer extends AtlassianWikiRenderer implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CMRRenderer.class);
    public static final String TYPE = "cmr-renderer";

    @JiraImport
    private final EventPublisher eventPublisher;

    @Autowired
    public CMRRenderer(@JiraImport EventPublisher eventPublisher_f,
                       ApplicationProperties applicationProperties,
                       VelocityRequestContextFactory velocityRequestContextFactory,
                       FeatureManager featureManager) {
        super(eventPublisher_f, applicationProperties, velocityRequestContextFactory, featureManager);
        this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher_f;
    }

    /**
     * Called when the plugin has been enabled.
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        log.info("[CMP] Enabling plugin");
        eventPublisher.register(this);
    }

    /**
     * Called when the plugin is being disabled or removed.
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        log.info("[CMP] Disabling plugin");
        eventPublisher.unregister(this);
    }

    public String getRendererType() {
        return TYPE;
    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.vladmak.ringcentral</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-cmp-plgin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <organization>
        <name>VLADmak</name>
        <url>https://www.linkedin.com/in/vladmak/</url>
    </organization>
    <name>JIRA CMP Plugin</name>
    <description>Add panel with CMRs details</description>
    <packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add dependency on jira-core if you want access to JIRA implementation classes as well as the sanctioned API. -->
        <!-- This is not normally recommended, but may be required eg when migrating a plugin originally developed against JIRA 4.x -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-annotation</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- WIRED TEST RUNNER DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.testrunner.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2-atlassian-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Uncomment to use TestKit in your project. Details at https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jira-testkit -->
        <!-- You can read more about TestKit at https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Plugin+Tutorial+-+Smarter+integration+testing+with+TestKit -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-testkit-client</artifactId>
            <version>${testkit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.renderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-renderer</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.9</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jira-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${amps.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <productVersion>${jira.version}</productVersion>
                    <productDataVersion>${jira.version}</productDataVersion>
                    <!-- Uncomment to install TestKit backdoor in JIRA. -->
                    <!--
                    <pluginArtifacts>
                        <pluginArtifact>
                            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jira-testkit-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>${testkit.version}</version>
                        </pluginArtifact>
                    </pluginArtifacts>
                    -->
                    <enableQuickReload>true</enableQuickReload>
                    <!-- See here for an explanation of default instructions: -->
                    <!-- https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/configuration-of-instructions-in-atlassian-plugins -->
                    <instructions>
                        <Atlassian-Plugin-Key>${atlassian.plugin.key}</Atlassian-Plugin-Key>
                        <!-- Add package to export here -->
                        <Export-Package>com.example.plugins.tutorial.api,</Export-Package>
                        <!-- Add package import here -->
                        <Import-Package>org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional", org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional", *</Import-Package>
                        <!-- Ensure plugin is spring powered -->
                        <Spring-Context>*</Spring-Context>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>atlassian-spring-scanner</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scannedDependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-external-jar</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </scannedDependencies>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <jira.version>7.13.0</jira.version>
        <amps.version>8.0.2</amps.version>
        <plugin.testrunner.version>2.0.1</plugin.testrunner.version>
        <atlassian.spring.scanner.version>1.2.13</atlassian.spring.scanner.version>
        <!-- This property ensures consistency between the key in atlassian-plugin.xml and the OSGi bundle's key. -->
        <atlassian.plugin.key>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</atlassian.plugin.key>
        <!-- TestKit version 6.x for JIRA 6.x -->
        <testkit.version>6.3.11</testkit.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Looks like the problem with around spring. If I delete @Comment module loads. But problem with EventPublisher occurred.

Comment: Hi Can you please share how could you solve this. I have same issue and could not find in documentation if I have missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

This class [JiraRendererPlugin](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/7.0.5/com/atlassian/jira/issue/fields/renderer/JiraRendererPlugin.html) is part of

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jira.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

You are using the correct scope and everything else seems legit.

I suggest to erase your local copy jira-api, v7.13.0

```
C:\Applications\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.0.16\repository\com\atlassian\jira\jira-api\7.13.0
```

After erasing, re run atlas-run or atlas-debug

I am not sure if this would fix it. Just a wild guess.

Comment: Doesn't help :( But thanks for your advise.    I found jar here c/Users/vladislav.lehelt/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/jira/jira-api/7.13.0/ and checked if class stored in file - JiraRendererPlugin is there.

Comment: This jar belongs to your IDE, Jira (atlas-run) uses a different one

Comment: You should be able to find another within the plugin SDK directory atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.0.##

Comment: There are on libraries  in atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.0.  As I see atlassian is using .m2/repository. I deleted it and restart jira - lib appeared. Error is the same.

Comment: @VladLehelt It would be nice if you can please share how could you solve this If you have  done so. I have exact same error and yet could not find in documentation if I have misses something.