# Jira Plugin Build error : FileNotFound Exception OSGi

Tags: java, spring, osgi, jira-plugin

Hi I have build my plugin which fails to start with error as

```
Failed to parse configuration class 

[com.q.plugins.config.MyPluginJavaConfig]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: OSGi resource[classpath:com/atlassian/plugins/osgi/javaconfig/configs/beans/ModuleFactoryBean.class|bnd.id=187|bnd.sym=com.q.plugins.jira_dc_plugin] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                           OSGi resource[classpath:com/atlassian/plugins/osgi/javaconfig/configs/beans/ModuleFactoryBean.class|bnd.id=187|bnd.sym=com.q.plugins.jira_dc_plugin] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

My Setup

```
    <jira.version>8.20.2</jira.version>
    <platform.version>5.2.0</platform.version>
    <refapp.version>5.3.0</refapp.version>
    <amps.version>8.1.2</amps.version>
    <plugin.testrunner.version>2.0.2</plugin.testrunner.version>
    <osgi.javaconfig.version>0.5.0</osgi.javaconfig.version>
    <spring.version>5.0.10.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

with OpenJDK 1.8 (java version "1.8.0_281")

My findings

- Using atlasian SDK maven and repository
- tried on clean start up using atlas- commands
- same error when manually deployed to running Jira instance in docker

Followed - https://bitbucket.org/atlassian_tutorial/atlassian-plugins-osgi-javaconfig-demo/src/master/

Found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62164999/beandefinitionstoreexception-failed-to-parse-configuration-class-because-it) but has no proper pointers to answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you executing this in an OSGi container?

Comment: Jira is an OSGi container